# How to remove blank array from autocomplete data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to remove blank array from autocomplete data.I mean how to delete or remove blank array from autocomplete output list?

```
   $(function() {
var available_tags=[  <?php 
foreach(glob('../image/imagefiles/*.*') as $key=>$filename){
      if($key==0)
          {echo "'".$filename."'";}
          else
          {echo ",'".$filename."'";}
     }
   ?> ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
             minLength: 0,
             source: available_tags,
                     });
             });
```

```
<div class="ui-widget">
      <input id="tags" size="50">
    </div>
```

Output :
`.`
`..`
`image1`
`image2`

Need Output :
`image1`
`image2`

Comment: The entries `.` and `..` are not "blank". They are references to the current and the parent directory. That makes sense since these nodes are indeed also contained in a directory listing. If you want to remove those from your array, then either use the `unset()` function, or, when iterating over the `glob` result, simply ignore them.

Comment: how to hide/remove this?

Comment: I said so in the comment. Did you read it to the end? I gave an example in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the two references `.` and `..` (those entries are *not* blank, but references to the current and the parent directory) in the listing you get as returned from the call to `glob()` you can simply ignore them when iterating over the result:

```
<?php
$elements = array();
foreach(glob('../image/imagefiles/*.*') as $key=>$filename) {
    if(!in_array($filename, array('.', '..'))) {
        $elements[] = "'".$filename."'";
    }
}
echo implode(',', $elements);
```

You probably also want to add some html markup in there and htmlescape() the file names, but this snippet should help to point out how to skip the entries...

Comment: It show me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' ...`

Comment: Ah, then you have a very old php version, one second, I will change it... Should be better now. Remember to upgrade your php some time, those old php versions contain security issues that have been fixed in newer versions.